# Python: How to call index 100

Tags: python

I'm using the string module and was curious how to call index 100 from string.printable?

```
len(string.printable)
100
string.printable[98]
'\x0b'
string.printable[99]
'\x0c'
string.printable[100]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Probably sounds weird. I know I can use string.printable[-1] but I'm using this for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot that counting starts at 0 so its 0-99 and not 1-100. 
The 100th element is at `string.printable[99]`

EDIT: assuming you want to loop around, you should use the modulus operator `%`
so to access the 100th item in a 100 item list you would do:

```
string.printable[99%100]
```

to get the 180th item in a 100 item list you would do:

```
string.printable[179%100]
```